# how to get a PHP script to make javascript in li elements

Tags: php, javascript

My PHP script queries a database and returns the rows as li elements to a div in a jQuery Dialog. It does this by building an array in the PHP while loop that processes the query row responses. Each li element has some data, an HTML button, and some javascript to execute on that li element when the button is clicked.

If I write "bad HTML" with the same id for each li element, the javascript executes, but only on the first li element. When I write "good HTML" with a unique id for each li element, I can't get the javascript to execute. I've researched and tried lots of things, but can't find anything this complicated to fix this. What should I do? Here's the stripped down code. The problem seems to be in the lengthy $error_ListActives line, but I'm open to suggestions.

```
$rowCount = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
    $storedStreetAddress = $row["streetAddress"];
    $storedCity = $row['city'];
    $error_NumberOfActives = "<li>Welcome back. You have . . .</li>";
    $errorMessages[0] = $error_NumberOfActives;
    $idMaker = "inactive" . $rowCount;
    $error_ListActives = "<li> $storedStreetAddress, $storedCity $idMaker
    <button type='button' id=$idMaker onclick='makeInactive()'>Pause this</button>
    <script type='text/javascript'>function makeInactive()
    //do stuff 
    {document.getElementById($idMaker).innerHTML='Inactive Completed';}
    </script> </li>";
    $errorMessages[] = $error_ListActives;
    $rowCount++;
    }
foreach( $errorMessages as $statusMessage ) {
    echo $statusMessage;
}
```

Please be specific, and code is helpful. I don't follow general instructions well in this area, as I'm a newbie with PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to end up with a lot of problems here because you are writing your javascript function inside a while loop. That means that you will get several copies of the same function, and only the last one is going to actually fire!

To fix this, write a generic javascript function for `makeInactive(id)` and then just call it with the `id` of the element you are working on.

Outside of the php loop:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>function makeInactive(id)
//do stuff 
{document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='Inactive Completed';}
</script>
```

Then change the php loop to:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
$storedStreetAddress = $row["streetAddress"];
$storedCity = $row['city'];
$error_NumberOfActives = "<li>Welcome back. You have . . .</li>";
$errorMessages[0] = $error_NumberOfActives;
$idMaker = "inactive" . $rowCount;
$error_ListActives = "<li> $storedStreetAddress, $storedCity $idMaker
<button type='button' id='$idMaker' onclick='makeInactive($idMaker)'>Pause this</button>
 </li>";
$errorMessages[] = $error_ListActives;
$rowCount++;
}
```

Comment: Hmm he was jQuery, why not just place all the li in one class then operate on that set?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but he's not actually using jQuery here... these `$vars` are php.

Comment: @JeffreyBlake, Thank you for a clear explanation. I changed the php loop, as suggested. I put the makeInactive function in the $error_NumberOfActives instruction, inside the li element. I tried this new $error_NumberOfActives instruction 1. in its current place (looped several times,but only 1 instance is created), and 2. before the while loop. The "Pause This" button appears in each li item for both cases. In both cases, the button does not fire - no Completed message appears on any click. Is it possible that no communication occurs across li elements - or what?

Comment: Javascript errors tend to be silent. Check your javascript console to see what is happening. I will note that I just noticed there were no quotes around the `id=$idMaker` part (ie it should be `id='$idMaker'`), and that could cause this type of issue.

Comment: Woohoo! The correct syntax for the button tag is -   <button type='button' id='$idMaker' onclick='makeInactive(id)'>  Talk about being very picky! - but it works.  Thanks for the clues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
<button onClick="makeInactive(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>);">...</button>
```

embed the ID code as a parameter to your MakeInactive() call. Other alternatives are to simply use some DOM, e.g.

```
<li id="xxx"><button onclick="makeInactive(this);">...</button></li>

<script>
function makeInactive(el) {
  el.getParent('li').disable(); // not real code, but shows the basic idea
}
</script>
```

Comment: But look into his while loop. He's creating the same exact function multiple times. It's just all no good.

Comment: Yes, that's the OP's problem and they can figure that out themselves. Once they get the basic idea of how to fix the actual call mechanics, everything else would hopefully flow and teach them something.

Comment: @MarcB, I tried your approach as best as I could understand it. The button tag changed to <button type='button' id=$idMaker onclick='makeInactive(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>  Nothing executes. I get an Internal System Error message. I tried a bunch of these php echo style variations yesterday on my own, and all of them generated this error. I don't understand your DOM proposal. Does xxx mean all the id's are the same? Should (this) be ($this) - we're in PHP here. Why would I use .disable()?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're creating the same exact function multiple times on your page. Your other buttons don't know which `makeInactive()` function to use. Why don't you give all of your buttons the same class, and then create ONE function that is included on the page that fires when the buttons are clicked.

No offense, but this is kind of bad markup here.

Comment: If all the buttons have the same class, they are not uniquely identified. Seems like a click on one li would fire the function on all li elements with the class. I want the function to act only on the data in one li element. And yes, I know its bad markup. I've been working on it for hours and it doesn't work.

Comment: In your javascript you would discern between the elements being selected. Have you gotten close to what you're looking to do?